# Are there configuration options in Create Next App to prevent building files on every save?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In Create Next App, are there any config options that will stop making build file every time I save a file? The compiling takes a lot of time when there are frequent changes.

I am trying to achieve faster compilation. I am using CNA and can't be using Vite. Need solution for Create Next App